# Replace specific expressions in file Java

Tags: java, string, file, replace, copy

I want to copy a annotated file, and replace those annotations in the new copy. However I am struggling on how to do the replacing. I am currently reading the whole file into a string and replacing the annotations before saving the string to a new file:

```
String file = null;

void openAnnotatedSource(String path){

    byte[] encoded = null;
    try {
        encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(anotatedpath + "/" + path));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening annotated source.");
    }

    file = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

}

void replaceAnotation(String anotation, String config){
    file = file.replace(anotation, config);
}

void replaceAnotation(String anotation, int config){
    file = file.replace(anotation, String.valueOf(config));
}

void createFinalSource(String path){
    try{
        Files.write(Paths.get(targetpath + "/" + path), file.getBytes());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldnt create " + targetpath + "/" + path);
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing this correctly because having the file the whole time as a string does not seem correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent text editor has a search&replace facility that supports regular expressions.

If however, you have reason to reinvent the wheel in Java, the approach you followed is a decent way, you are writing the modified contents into a different new file, so reading the contents from source file into a string and modifying the contents of string and creating a new file with updated string does not cause any problems.